# How to plot learning curve and validation curve while using pipeline

Tags: classification, scikit-learn

I would appreciate if you could let me know in the following example code:

```
from collections import Counter
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split,StratifiedKFold,learning_curve,validation_curve,GridSearchCV
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot_learning_curve(train_sizes, train_scores, test_scores, title, alpha=0.1):
    train_mean = np.mean(train_scores, axis=1)
    train_std = np.std(train_scores, axis=1)
    test_mean = np.mean(test_scores, axis=1)
    test_std = np.std(test_scores, axis=1)
    plt.plot(train_sizes, train_mean, label='train score', color='blue', marker='o')
    plt.fill_between(train_sizes, train_mean + train_std,
                     train_mean - train_std, color='blue', alpha=alpha)
    plt.plot(train_sizes, test_mean, label='test score', color='red', marker='o')
    plt.fill_between(train_sizes, test_mean + test_std, test_mean - test_std, color='red', alpha=alpha)
    plt.title(title)
    plt.xlabel('Number of training points')
    plt.ylabel('F-measure')
    plt.grid(ls='--')
    plt.legend(loc='best')
    plt.show()


def plot_validation_curve(param_range, train_scores, test_scores, title, alpha=0.1):
    train_mean = np.mean(train_scores, axis=1)
    train_std = np.std(train_scores, axis=1)
    test_mean = np.mean(test_scores, axis=1)
    test_std = np.std(test_scores, axis=1)
    plt.plot(param_range, train_mean, label='train score', color='blue', marker='o')
    plt.fill_between(param_range, train_mean + train_std,
                     train_mean - train_std, color='blue', alpha=alpha)
    plt.plot(param_range, test_mean, label='test score', color='red', marker='o')
    plt.fill_between(param_range, test_mean + test_std, test_mean - test_std, color='red', alpha=alpha)
    plt.title(title)
    plt.grid(ls='--')
    plt.xlabel('Parameter value')
    plt.ylabel('F-measure')
    plt.legend(loc='best')
    plt.show()

X, y = make_classification(n_classes=2, class_sep=2,weights=[0.9, 0.1], n_informative=3, n_redundant=1, flip_y=0, n_features=20, n_clusters_per_class=1, n_samples=1000, random_state=10)
print('Original dataset shape {}'.format(Counter(y)))

ln = X.shape
names = ["x%s" % i for i in range(1, ln[1] + 1)]

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y,random_state=0)
st=StandardScaler()

rg = LogisticRegression(class_weight = { 0:1, 1:6.5 }, random_state = 42, solver = 'saga',max_iter=100,n_jobs=-1)

param_grid = {'clf__C': [0.001,0.01,0.1,0.002,0.02,0.005,0.0007,.0006,0.0005],
              'clf__class_weight':[{ 0:1, 1:6 },{ 0:1, 1:4 },{ 0:1, 1:5.5 },{ 0:1, 1:4.5 },{ 0:1, 1:5 }]
              }

pipeline = Pipeline(steps=[('scaler', st),
                           ('clf', rg )])

cv=StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5,random_state=42)
rg_cv = GridSearchCV(pipeline, param_grid, cv=cv, scoring =  'f1')
rg_cv.fit(X_train, y_train)
print("Tuned rg best params: {}".format(rg_cv.best_params_))

ypred = rg_cv.predict(X_train)
print(classification_report(y_train, ypred))
print('######################')
ypred2 = rg_cv.predict(X_test)
print(classification_report(y_test, ypred2))

plt.figure(figsize=(9,6))
param_range1=[i / 10000.0 for i in range(1, 11)]
param_range2=[{0: 1, 1: 6}, {0: 1, 1: 4}, {0: 1, 1: 5.5}, {0: 1, 1: 4.5}, {0: 1, 1: 5}]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    train_sizes, train_scores, test_scores = learning_curve(
              estimator= rg_cv.best_estimator_ , X= X_train, y = y_train,
                train_sizes=np.arange(0.1,1.1,0.1), cv= cv,  scoring='f1', n_jobs= - 1)

    plot_learning_curve(train_sizes, train_scores, test_scores, title='Learning curve for Logistic Regression')

    train_scores, test_scores = validation_curve(
        estimator=rg_cv.best_estimator_, X=X_train, y=y_train, param_name="clf__C", param_range=param_range1,
        cv=cv, scoring="f1", n_jobs=-1)

    plot_validation_curve(param_range1, train_scores, test_scores, title="Validation Curve for C", alpha=0.1)

    train_scores, test_scores = validation_curve(
        estimator=rg_cv.best_estimator_, X=X_train, y=y_train, param_name="clf__class_weight", param_range=param_range2,
        cv=cv, scoring="f1", n_jobs=-1)

    plot_validation_curve(param_range2, train_scores, test_scores, title="Validation Curve for class_weight", alpha=0.1)
```

- Why when the  best estimator of GridSearchCv is passed into the learning curve function, it prints all the previous print lines several times?
- How to plot validation curve for class weight? `TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'dict'`

Comment: If you want to avoid printing, just add a ` semicolon` at the end of your call..

Comment: @Aditya Thanks a lot. Could you please let me know how I should exactly add 'semicolon'? Besides, how to tune class weight in a way that would be possible to plot validation curve for it?

Comment: The line which is making a lot of prints, just add a semicolon at the end, probably at your plotting calls I can't reproduce your problem, but this should fix this (atleast in jupyter notebooks it does)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With respect to the first and second question, the code should change into:

```
from collections import Counter
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, StratifiedKFold, learning_curve, validation_curve, GridSearchCV
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def plot_learning_curve(train_sizes, train_scores, test_scores, title, alpha=0.1):
    train_mean = np.mean(train_scores, axis=1)
    train_std = np.std(train_scores, axis=1)
    test_mean = np.mean(test_scores, axis=1)
    test_std = np.std(test_scores, axis=1)
    plt.plot(train_sizes, train_mean, label='train score', color='blue', marker='o')
    plt.fill_between(train_sizes, train_mean + train_std,
                     train_mean - train_std, color='blue', alpha=alpha)
    plt.plot(train_sizes, test_mean, label='test score', color='red', marker='o')

    plt.fill_between(train_sizes, test_mean + test_std, test_mean - test_std, color='red', alpha=alpha)
    plt.title(title)
    plt.xlabel('Number of training points')
    plt.ylabel('F-measure')
    plt.grid(ls='--')
    plt.legend(loc='best')
    plt.show()


def plot_validation_curve(param_range, train_scores, test_scores, title, alpha=0.1):
    param_range = [x[1] for x in param_range] 
    sort_idx = np.argsort(param_range)
    param_range=np.array(param_range)[sort_idx]
    train_mean = np.mean(train_scores, axis=1)[sort_idx]
    train_std = np.std(train_scores, axis=1)[sort_idx]
    test_mean = np.mean(test_scores, axis=1)[sort_idx]
    test_std = np.std(test_scores, axis=1)[sort_idx]
    plt.plot(param_range, train_mean, label='train score', color='blue', marker='o')
    plt.fill_between(param_range, train_mean + train_std,
                 train_mean - train_std, color='blue', alpha=alpha)
    plt.plot(param_range, test_mean, label='test score', color='red', marker='o')
    plt.fill_between(param_range, test_mean + test_std, test_mean - test_std, color='red', alpha=alpha)
    plt.title(title)
    plt.grid(ls='--')
    plt.xlabel('Weight of class 2')
    plt.ylabel('Average values and standard deviation for F1-Score')
    plt.legend(loc='best')
    plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    X, y = make_classification(n_classes=2, class_sep=2, weights=[0.9, 0.1], n_informative=3, n_redundant=1, flip_y=0,
                               n_features=20, n_clusters_per_class=1, n_samples=1000, random_state=10)
    print('Original dataset shape {}'.format(Counter(y)))

    ln = X.shape
    names = ["x%s" % i for i in range(1, ln[1] + 1)]

    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=0)
    st = StandardScaler()

    rg = LogisticRegression(class_weight={0: 1, 1: 6.5}, random_state=42, solver='saga', max_iter=100, n_jobs=-1)

    param_grid = {'clf__C': [0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 0.002, 0.02, 0.005, 0.0007, .0006, 0.0005],
                  'clf__class_weight': [{0: 1, 1: 6}, {0: 1, 1: 4}, {0: 1, 1: 5.5}, {0: 1, 1: 4.5}, {0: 1, 1: 5}]
                  }

    pipeline = Pipeline(steps=[('scaler', st),
                               ('clf', rg)])

    cv = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5, random_state=42)
    rg_cv = GridSearchCV(pipeline, param_grid, cv=cv, scoring='f1')
    rg_cv.fit(X_train, y_train)
    print("Tuned rg best params: {}".format(rg_cv.best_params_))

    ypred = rg_cv.predict(X_train)
    print(classification_report(y_train, ypred))
    print('######################')
    ypred2 = rg_cv.predict(X_test)
    print(classification_report(y_test, ypred2))

    plt.figure(figsize=(9, 6))
    param_range1 = [i / 10000.0 for i in range(1, 11)]
    param_range2 = [{0: 1, 1: 6}, {0: 1, 1: 4}, {0: 1, 1: 5.5}, {0: 1, 1: 4.5}, {0: 1, 1: 5}]

    train_sizes, train_scores, test_scores = learning_curve(
        estimator=rg_cv.best_estimator_, X=X_train, y=y_train,
        train_sizes=np.arange(0.1, 1.1, 0.1), cv=cv, scoring='f1', n_jobs=- 1)

    plot_learning_curve(train_sizes, train_scores, test_scores, title='Learning curve for Logistic Regression')

    train_scores, test_scores = validation_curve(
        estimator=rg_cv.best_estimator_, X=X_train, y=y_train, param_name="clf__C", param_range=param_range1,
        cv=cv, scoring="f1", n_jobs=-1)

    plot_validation_curve(param_range1, train_scores, test_scores, title="Validation Curve for C", alpha=0.1)

    train_scores, test_scores = validation_curve(
        estimator=rg_cv.best_estimator_, X=X_train, y=y_train, param_name="clf__class_weight", param_range=param_range2,
        cv=cv, scoring="f1", n_jobs=-1)

    plot_validation_curve(param_range2, train_scores, test_scores, title="Validation Curve for class_weight", alpha=0.1)
```

Comment: Sorry for my late response, I was a bit busy. Actually I'd seen your question when you posted it but didn't figure out what you meant by *pipeline*.

Comment: @Media Your welcome. Thanks. I think it is better to ask:How to plot validation curve for class weight? The above code intends to do it but it produces this error: TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'dict'

Comment: Which line has the mentioned error? We usually plot curves for specifying the learning rate and the error rate. Unfortunately I don't know what do you mean by *validation curve for weight*. Would you mind bringing a reference?

Comment: @Media Sorry for this inconvenience. It is the last line:     plot_validation_curve(param_range2, train_scores, test_scores, title="Validation Curve for class_weight", alpha=0.1).

Comment: @Media I think it should be possible to plot validation curve for all hyper-parameters: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_validation_curve.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-model-selection-plot-validation-curve-py

Comment: Dear @ebrahimi, what you have provided as a reference actually is something else. :) It has trained different models for different hyper-parameters, kernel parameter, then has plotted for them to investigate which performs better. That's for finding a model that performs best for cross-validation data. Are you familiar with those concepts? It has not plotted the hyper-parameters. It has plotted different accuracies for different models trained on a same data-set with different hyper-parameters. If you didn't figure out each part, tell me to provide you links for learning more :) movafaq bashid

Comment: Dear @Media. I appreciate you a lot for your time and consideration. I also want to plot different f1 scores for different models trained on the same data-set with different class-weight. Merci.

Comment: Actaully it is possible, do you need the formula?

Comment: @Media Yes, could you please provide the code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sure, take a look at [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/31253/28175).

Comment: @Media Sorry but I couldn't understand what you mean. Really, my problem is a binary class so I know how to compute f1 score. I just want to plot validation curve for class-weight (if we consider it as a hyper-parameter).

Comment: Sorry for late response. I don't know whether you're familiar with the term `hyper-parameter` or not but it has a simple definition. the weights and biases that your learning algorithms try to find are called `parameters` whilst the number of hidden layers, the number of neurons in each layer, learning rate, and such related things are called `hyper-parameter`. In the provided link I cannot see whether it's called a *hyper-parameter*. Furthermore, as I previously referred, the link *has trained different models for different hyper-parameters*. I guess what you want is learning curve, isn't it?

Comment: @Media Your welcome. Thanks. Really, I am studying accounting. However, according to this [post][1], since I want to tune class-weight, I think it could be considered as a hyper-parameter. It is not similar to parameters such as coefficients (or weights) in logistic regression or random state.


  [1]: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/14187/what-is-the-difference-between-model-hyperparameters-and-model-parameters

Comment: Yes, it is not and I've never seen someone does that. I guess it's better to watch a video about learning curve first to fully understand it. We usually use learning curves for finding out the problem of the ML algorithm, whether it suffers from high bias or high variance or maybe both. Although in DL era, it is not that much common. Anyway, I guess it is not a hyper-parameter to tune. Have you seen professor Andrew Ng's course on ML?

Comment: @Media. Thanks for your time. I have seen Ng's course. Besides, I know to some extent about learning curve, which is also plotted in the above code. However, weighting (tuning class weight) is an accepted approach to deal with class imbalances. For example, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29638117/r-tuning-svm-parameter-class-weights-in-e1071-package or https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/13490/how-to-set-class-weights-for-imbalanced-classes-in-keras

Comment: or https://www.svds.com/learning-imbalanced-classes/. Moreover, Sebastian Raschka didn't tell me that validation curve is not plotted for class-weight. Best regards,

Comment: About your first comment, I completely agree but the latter, maybe I've not heard about it :)

Comment: I didn't find a specific code? do you want to put it here?

Answer (score 2):

Currently (sklearn 0.22), with the example provided in the question, there's a future warning that sklearn 0.24 will raise an error at the line 72:

`cv = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5, random_state=42)`

> \lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection_split.py:296: FutureWarning: Setting a random_state has no effect since shuffle is False. This will raise an error in 0.24. You should leave random_state to its default (None), or set shuffle=True.
>     FutureWarning

According to the `StratifiedKFold` [documentation:](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold.html)

> **shuffle : boolean, optional**
>   Whether to shuffle each class’s samples before splitting into batches.
>   **random_state: int, RandomState instance or None, optional, default=None**
>   If int, random_state is the seed used by the random number generator; If RandomState instance, random_state is the random number generator; If None, the random number generator is the RandomState instance used by np.random. Only used when shuffle is True. This should be left to None if shuffle is False.
>   **Notes**
>   The implementation is designed to: (...)
>   Preserve order dependencies in the dataset ordering, when shuffle=False: all samples from class k in some test set were contiguous in y, or separated in y by samples from classes other than k.

Aside the future warning to be addressed, the default `shuffle=False` ensure reproducibility because it preserves the datasets ordering. So far, so good.

However, without knowing the dataset order is also random, only with `StratifiedKFold(..., shuffle=True`) one can ensure there won't be any dataset ordering bias affecting `StratifiedKFold`.

As the dataset generator `make_classification` was used with its default `shuffle=True' there won't be a dataset ordering bias issue this time:

According to `make_classification` [documentation:](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.make_classification.html)

> Without shuffling, X horizontally stacks features in the following order: the primary n_informative features, followed by n_redundant linear combinations of the informative features, followed by n_repeated duplicates, drawn randomly with replacement from the informative and redundant features. The remaining features are filled with random noise. Thus, without shuffling, all useful features are contained in the columns X[:, :n_informative + n_redundant + n_repeated].

In order to just solve the future error, remove the useless `random_state=42`:
`cv = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5)`

In order to solve the future error in situations one can't ensure the dataset ordering is random:
`cv = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True, random_state=42)` or even
`cv = StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits=5, random_state=42)`